# How to play video mp4 from jQuery image slider?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, video, mp4

I got a WordPress site, now updated to latest 5.0.3.
I have a working jQuery image slider were some of the (so called) images are links to video .mp4 files.

What would be the best way to play the video when the presenting image is visible?
I want to play the video on the area of the image.

I am not looking for a plugin but simple php/JS coding. Thanks!

Comment: you want show video on slider ? I'm not clear

Comment: @komeilmajidi Exactly. I want to play the video on the area of the image. Thanks

Comment: Do you use an plugin? I write a code for your plugin? or do I write code for you to do this with the help of php and js?

Comment: @komeilmajidi I am looking for a simple solution to embed in my code. I can code PHP and JS that will be needed

Comment: I din't notice . Do you want to have a php code to add to WordPress and create a video slider? Or do you want to use the plugin and expand the plugin to display the movie?

Comment: @komeilmajidi Any solution (with or without a plugin) can be good for me. But is must support showing also (and mainly) images in the slider

Comment: ok i answer your question

Comment: @komeilmajidi Sorry, this is not what I am looking for. You may use a plugin AS PART of your solution.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: No. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501837/how-to-play-a-video-in-jquery-image-slider