# How to play a video in jQuery image slider?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, mp4

I have a jQuery slider that I wrote in jQuery in WordPress site.

I want to enable it to play video if the src extension is "mp4".

Any ideas?

Here is an example of the HTML generated: (please note the first img src is a link to a video)

I would like to enable the visitor click play button to start the video.

```
<div id="img-container" style="width: 2828.1px; padding-right: 886px;">                    
    <div class="picture_holder">
        <div class="picture">
            <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/VideoClip.mp4" height="1080" width="842" alt="" title="" style="height: 414px; width: 323px;">
            <h4 class="captioning"><br><span class="rtl"></span></h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="picture_holder">
        <div class="picture">
            <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/railings.png" height="612" width="600" alt="" title="" style="height: 414px; width: 230px;">
            <h4 class="captioning"><br><span class="rtl"></span></h4>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="picture_holder">
        <div class="picture">
            <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/railing-1.png" height="600" width="462" alt="" title="" style="height: 414px; width: 177px;">
            <h4 class="captioning"><br><span class="rtl"></span></h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<img>` tag is for images only. For videos you need `<video>`. There's a tutorial on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Comment: @user78403 True. I am looking for js code to replace it online

Comment: So you're looking for code that scans your page for `<img>`s with videos in it and replaces them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I was looking for: (will replace every mp4 link with video tag):

```
$('.picture_holder .picture > img').each(function(index){
               console.log("index="+index+"  Video src = "+ $(this).attr('src') + "<<<");
               let imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
               if (imgsrc.indexOf(".mp4") >0) {
                   console.log("want to replace");
                   $(this).parent().prepend('<video width="320" height="600" controls><source src="'+imgsrc+'" type="video/mp4"></video>');
                   $(this).remove();
               } 
        });
```

It replaces the `img` element with `video` element.

I use `parent().prepend()` simply because `replaceWith()` is not working here.

Few fixes are still missing to place it correctly, but it works.